# Import error in imagej. import utility.Service?

Tags: importerror, imagej

I'm trying to run this CannyEdge-detection algorithm on ImageJ. The code is here on the link given. The problem is its not able to import utility.Service as given in the file. I cant find any such plugin. Please help.

```
 http://svg.dmi.unict.it/iplab/imagej/Plugins/Edge%20Detectors/Canny/EdgeDetection/edge/Canny_.java
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file is also part of the source code of the plugin - you can download it from:

http://svg.dmi.unict.it/iplab/imagej/Plugins/Edge%20Detectors/Canny/EdgeDetection/utility/Service.java